# DistinctCount with calculate in card representation

Tags: count, powerbi, dax

I want to get the number of line in straight table. I use this formula dax :

```
CALCULATE(DISTINCTCOUNT(TABLE[Ref.]),
                 ALLEXCEPT(TABLE, TABLE[Ref.]))
```

But the the total return me the number total of reference i have in Power instead return me the number of reference which selected.
The result here is 3.
[image]

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Why not just use `Count ref. = DISTINCTCOUNT(TABLE[Ref.])` ?